# Storing a Randomly generated number in a variable

Tags: c

Im trying to make a program that calculates out a math equation, Im getting stuck on how i generate a random number from 0.00 to 1.00 and store it in a variable a.

this is my code so far, im stuck to how now take that number and store it for future use. I need to store that random number in a, and hten use it in a loop, and then generate a new random number and use it in the 2nd cycle of the loop.

EDIT
this is what i have been working on now, it is suppose to calculate the number of times a random number is inside the area, count it, and then devide by the number of times run, but im not getting any output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void initrand(void) 
{ 
srand(time(0)); 
} 

float randfloat(void) 
{ 
return rand()/(float)RAND_MAX; 
} 



int main(void)
{
int n = 10;
float x;
float y;
float pi = 3.1415;
float rootxy;
initrand();
int z = 0;
int inside = 0;
x = randfloat();
y = randfloat();
float area = 0.25 * pi;
float calculatedpi;
rootxy = sqrt(pow(x,2) + (pow(y,2)));

while (z < n){
    if (rootxy > area) {
        inside++;
        z++;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
    calculatedpi = (inside/n);
}


printf("%f", calculatedpi);
```

}

Comment: [drand48](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/seed48.html)

Comment: Did you really mean to nest `initrand()` and `randfloat()`? Nesting functions aren't standard C.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void initrand(void) 
{ 
    srand(time(0)); 
} 

float randfloat(void) 
{ 
    return rand()/(float)RAND_MAX; 
} 

int main(void)
{
    initrand();
    float a = randfloat();
    return 0;
}
```

1. You can't nest functions like in some other languages.
2. You had non-matching parentheses in the `initrand` function.
3. I fixed the declarations of your functions, use `void` when there are no parameters, `initrand` doesn't return anything.
4. Your division by `RAND_MAX+1` was a little messed up. Simply divide by `RAND_MAX` and the result will be in the closed interval [0,1]. And the syntax for the conversion to `float` was not quite right.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code:

- You shouldn't use nested functions. Some compilers support them as an extension but it's not standard. Define `randfloat` and `initrand` outside `main`
- <strike>The function `initrand` does too little. Why not call `srand((time(0));` from `main` ?</strike>
- Your `initrand` function is declared as returning a double but it doesn't return anything (and the way it's named it shouldn't). If you need to use such a function, why not make it return `void` ?
- **You should rarely use `float`. Why not use `double`** ?

That said, you can do this to store that random value:

```
double randdouble() 
{ 
    return rand()/((double)RAND_MAX + 1); 
}

int main()
{
    double x = randdouble();
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Why rarely use `float`? `double` is overkill for many applications, computer graphics included.

Comment: @Shahbaz Even if it's overkill (which I'm not sure it is) there is little to be lost from using `double`. Using `float` will reduce precision without increasing performance.

Comment: "The function initrand does too little" is so wrong it makes me want to cry. The name clearly specifies the intent; the behavior is localized so that changing the algorithm to a more sophisticated one (i.e. reading seed from /dev/urandom) only touches the function; you can reset the RNG in other places if you need to. While the idea of global RNG state is wrong, once you use it there is nothing wrong with having an initrand function that just does srand.

Comment: @zeuxcg I didn't think about resetting the generator, or using other seeds. Thanks for the heads up :-)

Comment: I'm with @zeuxcg, the tears are flowing

Comment: @DavidHeffernan :-)) Actually the way zeuxcg commented, I actually felt bad for messing up that point.

Comment: What's the rationale behind the `RAND_MAX+1`? I know it was in the Q but it seems off to me.

Comment: @David Heffernan I was thinking of an open interval `[0, 1)`. And since `RAND_MAX` is already cast to `double` it can't overflow. Obviously omitting the `+1` would be perfectly valid.

Comment: That's a clopen interval. Great word that. Just had to use it!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I actually pondered for a bit: "how do I call this thing?". Awesome!

Comment: @cnicutar, I'm talking about this situation here, but with `double` you do gain a lot of performance increase. You are reducing the size of data by half. If you are doing computer graphics, well OpenGL changes it to float anyway, so you don't really have higher precision. In other programs, if you have huge data, you have fewer page swaps and more cache hits. So, don't make that line **bold**, using `float` or `double` depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get random `double` numbers in a specified range you can use this function

```
// Return a random double from a to b
double randomDouble(double a, double b)
{
    return = ( rand() / ( (double)RAND_MAX + 1.0)) 
             * (b - a) + a;
}
```